# Multer Encoding Issue: localized text getting converted random character

Tags: node.js, encoding, multipartform-data, multer, 7-bit

I am using multer's upload.single to extract a csv file from request. When converting the buffer given by multer's upload fn to string, I observed localized text characters (like **À**) are getting converted to some random character( like **ï¿½** ).The encoding which multer uses is 7bit. Is there any way to get data in utf-8 encoding.

**contentType:** multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------685735458832809176548913

**Multer's file details:**

```
fieldname: 'file',
originalname: 'Sample.csv',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'text/csv',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue, When converting the buffer to string add 'latin1' as encoding

```
request.file.buffer.toString('latin1')
```